# Difference between sequence points and operator precedence? 0_o

Tags: c++

Let me present a example :

`a = ++a;`

The above statement is said to have undefined behaviors ( I already read the article on UB on SO)

but according precedence rule operator prefix `++` has higher precedence than assignment operator `=`

so `a` should be incremented first then assigned back to a. so every evaluation is known, so why it is UB ?

Comment: Just for the fun of it, apparently in C++11 that statement seems to be perfectly defined, unlike `a = a++;` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4183735#4183735). It would be so much more fun to be able to yell "undefined behavior", but now one would have to be much more careful...

Comment: `++a` doesn't guarantee that `a` first will be set, then it's new value will be returned. Only that `a` will be set some time before the next sequence point and that `a + 1` will be returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The important thing to understand here is that operators can *produce values* and can also have *side effects*.

For example `++a` produces (evaluates to) `a + 1`, but it also has the side effect of incrementing `a`. The same goes for `a = 5` (evaluates to 5, also sets the value of `a` to 5).

So what you have here is two side effects which change the value of `a`, both happening between sequence points (the visible semicolon and the end of the previous statement).

**It does not matter that due to operator precedence the order in which the two operators are evaluated is well-defined, because the order in which their side effects are processed is still undefined.**

Hence the UB.

Comment: Had to come here to say thank you! "It does not matter that..." that solved my confusion completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Precedence is a consequence of the grammar rules for parsing expressions. The fact that `++` has higher precedence than `=` only means that `++` binds to its operand "tighter" than `=`. In fact, in your example, there is only one way to parse the expression because of the order in which the operators appear. In an example such as `a = b++` the grammar rules or precedence guarantee that this means the same as `a = (b++)` and not `(a = b)++`.

Precedence has very little to do with the order of evaluation of expression or the order in which the side-effects of expressions are applied. (Obviously, if an operator operates on another expression according to the grammar rules - or precedence - then the value of that expression has to be calculated before the operator can be applied but most independent sub-expressions can be calculated in any order and side-effects also processed in any order.)

Answer (score 1):

> why it is UB ?

Because it is an attempt to change the variable `a` two times before one sequence point:

- ++a
- operator=

Comment: I know that already , but what's the difference? -> what wrong with considering operator precedence , why they are wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is done 1st, if it causes an undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Sequence point evaluation #6: At the end of an initializer; for example, after the evaluation of 5 in the declaration int a = 5;. from Wikipedia.

You're trying to change the same variable, a, twice.  ++a changes it, and assignment (=) changes it.  But the sequence point isn't complete until the end of the assignment.  So, while it makes complete sense to us - it's not guaranteed by the standard to give the right behavior as the standard says not to change something more than once in a sequence point (to put it simply).

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of subtle, but it could be interpreted as one of the following (and the compiler doesn't know which:

```
a=(a+1);a++;
a++;a=a;
```

This is because of some ambiguity in the grammar.

Comment: Although C++ is grammar is ambiguous in some places, this isn't one of them. The parsing of `a = ++a;` is completely unambiguous it's just that the behaviour is not defined.

Comment: True, but what the semantics of the grammar is ambigous, hence undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "semantics of the grammar". The expression has explicitly undefined behavior, I don't believe there's any ambiguity.

Comment: The semantics are ambiguous, thus they cannot be defined, and that is why it's called undefined behavior. If there where no ambiguity then it would be defined behavior.

Comment: I can't help thinking that we must be arguing at cross purposes; this may be because we don't agree on the definitions of some fundamental terms.

Comment: Yes, and I gave you the explanation of the difference in terms. 'Ambiguous' literally means 'not clearly defined', which is a synonym to 'undefined'. Thus ambiguous behavior is undefined behavior. 'Semantics' literally means 'study of meaning', and the meaning of code is to do something, have some *behavior*. Thus 'ambiguous semantics' means exactly the same thing as 'undefined behavior'.

Comment: OK, that explains my confusion. I haven't ever come across anyone use the phrase "ambiguous semantics" as an alternative to "undefined behavior" before. I still thing that your original use of the phrase "some ambiguity in the grammar" is misleading, though.

Comment: Yes, as I said I concurred with that it was misleading, because I meant the semantics. The documentation of the grammar describes the semantics too, hence the confusion.